# How do you get the current count from CSemaphore?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc, semaphore

I am trying to debug a multi-threaded program that uses [CSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78w43c88%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to limit the size of a buffer.

How do you get the current value of the semaphore counter from this class? It doesn't seem to be directly accessed from any of its members, and I can't seem to find any functions that will give me it either.

Comment: It is forbidden knowledge.  Because if you could get it, you'll get the wrong value sometimes.  Don't mess with threading races, they'll eat you.

Comment: @Hans: Forget quantum computing, this is quantum programming!

Comment: Why not just trace the occurrence to debug and count manually? You could even trace in a "CSV like" format and paste into excel so you can do some formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to care - this is a semaphore, not thread-shared counter.

That said, you might abuse the `ReleaseSemaphore` API's `lpPreviousCount` output parameter

```
BOOL WINAPI ReleaseSemaphore(
  __in       HANDLE hSemaphore,
  __in       LONG lReleaseCount,
  __out_opt  LPLONG lpPreviousCount
);
```

The idea:

```
CSemaphore &mySemaphore = /*initialized from somewhere*/;

HANDLE hsem = (HANDLE) mySemaphore; // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5zcch25.aspx
LONG peeked_count;
::ReleaseSemaphore(hsem, 1 /*can't be 0, sorry!*/, &peeked_count);
```

Note that unfortunately you'll have to actually release the semaphore (lReleaseCount must be >0)

Comment: Thanks. Usually I don't care what the counter is, but I do when I'm debugging! What I really want to do is trigger a breakpoint when the counter is at 0 or max, but I guess this isn't an east thing to do. I guess I'm going to have to add an `int` counter alongside the semaphore and manually increment/decrement it everywhere the semaphore is locked/released :-/

Answer (score 0):

That is not easily possible. If you really want to do that, all I can think of doing is to try to lock the semaphore manually as many times as possible, until the locking fails, with 0 time-out, and unlocking immediately after that. You will also have to remember the max count. E.g., untested code:

```
int max_count = 5;
CSemaphore sem (max_count, max_count);
/*...*/
int count = 0;
while (sem.Lock (0))
  ++count;
for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
  sem.Unlock(count);
std::cout << "the lock count is " << (max_count - count);
```

**EDIT:**

After seeing [sehe's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119986/how-do-you-get-the-current-count-from-csemaphore/7120191#7120191), I think a better solution would be combination of both:

```
int max_count = 5;
CSemaphore sem (max_count, max_count);
if (sem.Lock(0))
{
  LONG peeked_count;
  ::ReleaseSemaphore(hsem, 1 /*can't be 0, sorry!*/, &peeked_count);
  /* peeked_count has the count */
}
else
{
  /* I do not think it is safe to release the semaphore even if just for debugging. */
  /* max_count has the count */
}
```

Comment: WOW. That assumes that the Semaphore is being used single-threaded. defeating the whole purpose of the semaphore. This code would serve well as a highly concocted example of a complex  race condition tangled web?

Comment: @sehe, any count that you get anyhow can be invalid before you print it or do anything with it. I am only assuming that the application is such that all other uses of the semaphore will block until they can acquire it.

Comment: Unless you use the Release API that returns the previous count; this is an atomic count from a well-defined moment in time. No race.

Comment: @sehe: I think I now understand what you mean. But unless acquires/releases counts in the application are somehow asymmetric, it should work as well and give acquired count at the point in time where the `sem.Lock(0)` returns false.